# Access same server via both Remote-SSH and Remote-Tunnels in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, tunnel, visual-studio-code-server

I have a remote server that, depending on context, I would like to access through [SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) or through the [Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) mechanism.

Currently I have used mostly SSH, but I would like to explore Tunnels because I would also like to access this machine from a tablet through the browser, and it seems Tunnels is nice way of achieving this. At the same time I would like to keep accessing the same server via SSH when it's more convenient to do so.

Is it safe to setup BOTH access routes to the same server, and use them both (even simultaneously)? Any gotchas? Thanks.